# GLUT OpenGL Cube exturing error

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut, soil

I'm trying to texture a cube in openGL. I am using GLUT and Visual C++ 2010. I am using the popular imageloader SOIL.h and I'm using the code from a fellow user. The code is meant to draw a 3-D cube to the screen with textures applied to it. I have included SOIL.h in the header files folder in VC++ but every time i compile I get this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SOIL_load_OGL_texture referenced in function "int __cdecl LoadGLTextures(void)"
```

I will provide any extra information if needed.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glut.h>

#include "SOIL.h"

GLuint texture[6];//6 textures for 6 faces of the cube

GLfloat xRot,yRot,zRot;//control cube's rotation

int LoadGLTextures()
{
int Status = 0;
char *bmpFile[6]      {"BmpFile/1.bmp","BmpFile/2.bmp","BmpFile/3t.bmp","BmpFile/4.bmp","BmpFile/5.bmp","BmpFile/6.bmp"};

for (int i = 0;i < 6;++i){
    texture[i] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
        bmpFile[i],
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
    printf("texture[%d]: %d\n",i,texture[i]);
    if(texture[i] == 0){
        Status = 0;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[i]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);}
}

return Status;
}

int init(){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
    return 1;
}

void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);
    glRotatef(xRot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(yRot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(zRot,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[0]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glEnd(); 

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[1]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glEnd(); 

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glEnd(); 

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[3]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glEnd(); 

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[4]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glEnd(); 

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[5]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f); 
    glEnd(); 

    xRot += 0.3f;
    yRot += 0.4f;
    zRot += 0.5f;

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w,int h){
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w,(GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0f,(GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h,1,100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("Texture Map");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: library isn't linked properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to add the required library in the linker settings.

Add the libsoil.lib folder path to the visual studio linker settings.

You may have to build the library from source for windows if one is not already provided.